# Is the AWS Tutorial "Build a Serverless Web Application" broken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/

I've tried looking online, but it seems this isn't a common issue. I've followed all the steps successfully up until "Step 3: Populate the git repository"

When I run the commands, it gives me the following output.

```
> aws s3 cp s3://wildrydes-us-east-1/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website ./ --recursive
> fatal error: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

A couple of the common things I've already checked are:

1. I'm using the correct region. My CodeCommit repository is in `us-east-1`, and my `aws configure` region is also set to that.
2. My Access Key and Secret Key should be correct. I generated them for the corresponding IAM user and then input them via `aws configure`
3. I've configured the IAM properly (I think). The permissions I've given the IAM account are:

```
AdministratorAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AmazonS3ObjectLambdaExecutionRolePolicy
AmazonS3OutpostsFullAccess
AmazonS3OutpostsReadOnlyAccess
AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
AWSCodeCommitPowerUser
```

Even attempting to contact the bucket via `http` returns that the bucket does not exist. https://s3.amazonaws.com/wildrydes-us-east-1/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website

Is there anything else I missed? Is there a way to download this S3 bucket online or check that it even exists? Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: Looks like it's no longer maintained.

Comment: Ahhh, damn. That's frustrating. I spent an hour thinking it might've been something on my end.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the bucket **wildrydes-us-east-1** really exists and it is spelled correctly? I'll also say you should confirm that the bucket is actually in us-east-1.
If you've confirmed those, it might be a permission issue, as you also mention that your credentials 'should' be correct. Can you run *aws s3 ls* in your configured teminal? Do you see the bucket listed?

Comment: Hi @OlakunleAbiola, the S3 bucket in question is not one maintained by me, but rather a publicly accessible bucket maintained by AWS themselves, which they provide in the tutorial.

To quote the tutorial itself:
> Change directory into your repository and copy the static files from S3 using the following commands (make sure you change the Region in the following command to copy the files from the S3 bucket to the Region you selected at the beginning of this tutorial):
cd wildrydes-site
aws s3 cp s3://wildrydes-us-east-1/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website ./ --recursive

Comment: @B.Iguana It shouldn't stop you from there tho. You can use some template html. The only downside to that is your website may not look pretty.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc, I was considering doing that. I just wasn't sure if the website they provided had some additional functionality in the front-end which I'd need to re-implement. Either way, I think that's how I'll proceed.

Comment: Ah got it. I think as @jellycsc mentioned, you can proceed with your custom solution to get past that step. All the best.

Comment: @B.Iguana If you really want the same htmls from the tutorial, you can find it on GitHub. Here is an example I found. https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshops/tree/webapp-tutorial/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website

Comment: Accessing the wildrydes website at that URL doesn't return that the bucket does not exist. It returns access denied.

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same issue and realized AWS no longer maintains that bucket. So here, I have created an s3 bucket in a different region with all the required front-end code. Use this:

cd wildrydes-site

aws s3 cp s3://wildrydes-eu-central-1/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website ./ --recursive